# Python function for capping a string to a maximum length

Tags: python, string

Is there a function in Python, built-in or in the standard library, for capping a string to a certain length, and if the length was exceeded, append three dots (...) after it?

For example:

```
>>> hypothetical_cap_function("Hello, world! I'm a string", 10)
"Hello, ..."
>>> hypothetical_cap_function("Hello, world! I'm a string", 20)
"Hello, world! I'm..."
>>> hypothetical_cap_function("Hello, world! I'm a string", 50)
"Hello, world! I'm a string"
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
def cap(s, l):
    return s if len(s)<=l else s[0:l-3]+'...'
```

Comment: I'll take that as a **no** to it being in the standard library. Thanks for the function :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most flexibile (short of just slicing) way is to create a wrapper around `textwrap.wrap` such as: (bear in mind though, it does try to be *smart* about splitting in some places which may not get *exactly* the result you're after - but it's a handy module to know about)

```
def mywrap(string, length, fill=' ...'):
    from textwrap import wrap
    return [s + fill for s in wrap(string, length - len(fill))]

s = "Hello, world! I'm a string"
print mywrap(s, 10)
# ['Hello, ...', 'world! ...', "I'm a ...", 'string ...']
```

Then just take the elements you're after.